# Options to fix an old leaky shower valve

Tags: plumbing, shower, leak

The shower valve in my guest bathroom is leaking and I would like to replace it but it's fairly old and not compatible with the new mixer cartridges. I bought a brand new valve & cartridge but I'm a bit nervous to attempt replacing it because the hot & cold water pipes will need to be re-soldered and I'm not sure I have enough space to do a good job.

This is an Eljer valve which I believe has been discontinued. The shower handle is one of those where up-down controls the flow and left-right the temperature of the mixture.

Are there any other options? Maybe some sort of converter cartridge is available? I don't even know where to start looking nothing appears compatible.

I would like to switch to a single handle and replace the trim (to Moen or Delta or something) but don't know if that's possible without replacing the valve?

Here is what the valve looks like

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks fairly standard to me. I'd contact Eljer & see if Danco, Brasscraft or someone else has put out a replacement that fits. Otherwise, have you tried to rebuild the old valve with O-ring replacements & such? Eljer should be able to direct you to the right kit for the valve.

On the other hand, soldering will be difficult & could cause a fire in the wall if you're not experienced. So, either get a Plumber or get a [**SharkBite Threaded connector**](http://www.homedepot.com/p/SharkBite-1-2-in-Brass-Push-to-Connect-x-Female-Pipe-Thread-Adapter-U072LFA/202270500) so you can just cut the old valve loose & wrench in the new one. I updated the picture to show the correct valve that has screw shut-offs or stops (the silver screw).

[image: Valve & Connector]

Comment: I've soldered pipes once - in an exterior wall full with insulation and managed to NOT start a fire, but it was nerve wrecking. I would like to switch to a single handle and replace the trim (to Moen or Delta or something) but don't know if that's possible without replacing the valve?

Comment: Yeah, don't even bother trying the soldering then, it'll be more annoying than dangerous. I just updated my answer with a threaded valve that should address the problem...that one doesn't have integrated shut-offs, but you may be able to do those as the compression fittings themselves or install in-wall valves (compressions too) if you have an access panel.

Comment: Lost you there. If I cut out the old valve I still need to solder the nuts to the pipes right?

Comment: Nope. Compression fittings use a brass ring to cinch the pipe almost as securely as soldering. You'd slip the nut on the pipe & then the ring & just tighten the nut down to be done & leak free.

Comment: If you cut out the old valve, won't the pipes be slightly shorter? So you'd have to buy a slightly larger valve, or make up that lost pipe somehow, right?

Comment: Yep, but he's a sizing expert at this point.

Comment: @ventsyv I updated my answer & picture.